# PyQt QTextEdit text selection without moving the cursor (like ubuntu terminal)

Tags: pyqt

I've developed a shell (imitating the ubuntu terminal --> can only edit text after current prompt) by a PyQt QTextEdit.

The thing is when I select some text, the cursor moves as I'm selecting this text (so it disappers from the current command line) and I would like the cursor to stay where it is (only when I select text because I want it to move when I move it programmatically by `textEdit.moveCursor(...)`) at the same time I'm selecting the text.

Does anybody have any idea of how could I do that?

My solution for now, is to save the position at any change of it (except when it changes by a click), and when I copy some text en paste it, it'll be automatically pasted in the last position the cursor was before the click. That works perfectly but it's "ugly" for the user because, as I said, when he selects the text the cursor disappears of the current line and is where the user is selecting the text. Not like in ubuntu terminal.

Thanks in advance! And sorry for my english.

Adri

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an easy solution to implement this with a text editor API. A terminal is a hack, basically. It mixes a read-only element (anything above the current prompt) with a text editor.

My approach would be to create two text editors, make one read only and display the results of all operations there. If you hide the borders of the two editors, then it will look like a single one. You may have to forward a bunch of events (like scrolling with the keyboard) to the read-only display.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Do you think catching mousePressEvent and doubleClickMousePressEvent and implementing manually a selection of the text would be easier than what you say?

Comment: @adriapm Absolutely not. Try to select some text while a command appends text. If you don't do it correctly, the new text will appear where the mouse currently is.